# Can XCUITEST can implement the cucumber Feature files

Tags: swift, cucumber, xcuitest

Can we write the  Feature files and step definitions in Swift  Automation framework using XCUITEST Framework ?Is yes , Any jar files or plugins we need to install ?

I am unable to find much support in this

Answer (score 0):

While this is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow, I will oblige you an answer with [Cucumberish](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/Cucumberish). I have used it in the past, it works, but I generally steer clear of third party frameworks as they add a layer of complexity and leave you in the lurch if they lose support.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked a bit with [CucumberSwift](https://github.com/Tyler-Keith-Thompson/CucumberSwift) and got it to work fine, reading German-language Feature files and letting me define steps in Swift using all the functionality that XCUITest provides.

However, we have not adopted this in the end but are writing Feature files in Gherkin and then write ordinary `XCTestCases` that we link to the Feature files by mentioning Scenario names in comments. We develop the same functionality for three platforms and it was difficult to see how BDD tooling would work across all three or how we could make it work given the resources we have. Like [Mike Collins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2533443/mike-collins) we also felt that running without the complexity of additional frameworks was an added benefit.

Having said this, CucumberSwift seems promising, perhaps check out [this discussion about documentation](https://github.com/Tyler-Keith-Thompson/CucumberSwift/discussions/40) and add to it?